# Knife project that's not along view axis?

Tags: knife-tool

The [knife project tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html) cuts a mesh by projecting a curve along the view axis. Is it possible to do the same thing using the normals of the curve instead? Imagine engraving text onto a mesh modeling a ring worn on your finger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the knife tool specifically has the ability to project from a curve. A suggestion would be to first use a curve modifier and fit your mesh to the shape you want. Then project your knife cut onto the object. I used a circle to curve my mesh.
[image: check fit of curve modifier][image: project knife onto mesh][image: ring with text]

Comment: Perfect, thank you